# CHECK constraint for array column to verify length > 0

Tags: postgresql, constraint, null, check-constraints

I'm playing with postgres table validation rules and trying to set a `CHECK` constraint for an array column. An idea is to allow only arrays with length > 0.

Here is how I want to implement it:

```
create table words_table (
  id serial primary key, 
  words varchar(20)[] CHECK (array_length(words, 1) > 0)
);
```

But looks like it doesn't work. O_o

```
insert into words_table (words) values ('{}');
//INSERT 0 1
```

How to implement such a constraint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`array_length(words, 1)` will return `null` if the specified array dimension does not exists.  You should use `cardinality()` instead:

```
create table words_table 
(
  id serial primary key, 
  words varchar(20)[] CHECK (cardinality(words) > 0)
);
```

```
insert into words_table (words) values ('{}');
```

results in:

```
ERROR: new row for relation "words_table" violates check constraint "words_table_words_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (1, {}).
```

Answer (score 9):

The crucial point you may not be aware of, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

> It should be noted that a check constraint is satisfied if the check
> expression evaluates to **true or the null value**.

Bold emphasis mine.

Just rule out empty arrays:

```
CHECK (words <> '{}')
```

This still allows `words` to be `null`. You may want to add a `NOT NULL` constraint.
**Or** catch `null`in the `CHECK` constraint, too

```
CHECK ((words <> '{}') IS TRUE)
```